# Same class, 2 programs, different OpenMP speedups; MSVC2017

Tags: openmp, msvc14

I have a C++ class, several of whose functions have OpenMP parallel for loops.  I'm building it into two apps with MSVC2017, and find that one of those functions runs differently in the 2 apps.  The function has two separate parallel for loops.  In one build, the VS debugger shows them both using 7 cores for a solid second while processing a block of test data; in the other, it shows just two blips of multicore usage, presumably at the beginning of each parallel section, but only 1 processor runs most of the time.

These functions are deep inside the code for the class, which is identical in the 2 apps. The builds have the same compiler and linker options so far as I can see. I generate the projects with CMake and never modify them by hand.

Can anyone suggest possible reasons for this behavior? I am fully aware of other ways to parallelize code, so please don't tell me about those.  I am just looking for expertise on OpenMP under MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

I expect he two calls are passing in significantly different amounts of work. Consider (example, trivial, typed into this post, not compiled, not the way to write this!) code like

```
void scale(int n, double *d, double f) { 
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        d[i] = d[i] * f;
}
```

If invoked with a large vector where n == 10000, you'll get some parallelism and many threads working. If called with n == 3 there's obviously only work for three threads! 
If you use `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)` it's quite possible that even with ten or twenty iterations a single thread will execute most of them.

In summary: context matters.

Comment: Sorry, Jim.  The two instances are processing exactly the same input.